# Can I change leaflets popup event handlers?

Tags: leaflet

Currently the default behavior is when the layer that the popup is binded to is clicked, the popup will open, I want to change this click event into a context menu event. I am using the layer.bindpopup function and I cannot see how to do this using the options.

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/Popup.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind an additional handler or you don't bind the popup and use only your custom function.

```js
function customPop(e) {
    // your own code
    console.log(e);
}

layer.bindPopup('the popup text'); // delete it, if you don't want the popup
layer.on('contextmenu', customPop); // contextmenu or other events
```

In this example left click would open the normal Popup and right click (contextmenu) your own popup (menu) function.

Comment: This method worked but I had to use L.popup().openOn(map) and not use layer.bindPopup.